# Why can't I convert milliseconds from C# to a JavaScript Date Object?

Tags: javascript, .net, date

I've written a function in .net that returns a date.  I need to get that date into a Date Object in JavaScript.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date, I should be able to invoke `new Date(x)` where x is the number of milliseconds in my date.

Therefore, I've written the following in my ASP.net MVC 3 code:

```
ViewBag.x = new TimeSpan(someDate.Ticks).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Then, in JavaScript, I get the following code:

```
new Date( 63461023004794 )
```

The date being represented should be January 1st, 2012.

However, the date that JavaScript reads is December 31st, 3980.

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your .NET code is giving you the number of milliseconds since Jan. 1st, 0001.

The JavaScript constructor takes the number of milliseconds since Jan. 1st, 1970.

The easiest thing would probably be to change your .NET code to:

```
ViewBag.x = (someDate - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 3):

`someDate.Ticks` is measured since January 1<sup>st</sup>, 0001.

Javascript dates take milliseconds since January 1<sup>st</sup>, **1970**, UTC.

Comment: yep, needs to be milliseconds since January 1st, 1970

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `DateTime` structure counts ticks since 0001-01-01, while the `Date` object counts milliseconds since 1970-01-01.

Take the difference from 1970-01-01 as milliseconds:

```
ViewBag.x = (someDate - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: Reference material: the description of the DateTime structure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Unix calender's **epoch** is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. Assuming your times are already UTC (not a given):

```
DateTime someDate   = GetSomeDate() ;
DateTime UNIX_EPOCH = new DateTime(1970,1,1) ;
Timespan ts         = someDate - UNIX_EPOCH ;
```

should do you. Then pass javascript, the TimeSpan's `TotalMilliseconds` property.

Answer (score 0):

Rules:

> `C# Ticks` measures since `0001-01-01`.
>
> `Javascript dates` take milliseconds since `1970-01-01, UTC`.

Then you need **subtract `2665800000` milliseconds** from your `C#` `DateTime` variable (`someDate`):

> **`2665800000` is a const**: different between `1970-01-01` and `0001-01-01` as milliseconds

Use:

```
ViewBag.x = (someDate - new DateTime(2665800000)).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: There are 62135596800000 milliseconds from 0001-01-01 to 1970-01-01.  Unless I'm missing something.


let date = new Date(timestamp - 62135596800000).toDateString();